# Partition not appearing in the partition list after resizing with EaseUS?

Tags: windows, windows-10, easeus-partition-manager, partitionmanager

I resized a partition using EaseUS, but now the partition is not listed in the system.
however it's enlisted in the Disk Management volumes, but I can't open it from there:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/6gUFJpc.png]

please help!

Comment: Assign it a drive letter....

Answer (score 1):

Click on `change drive letter and path` and assign a drive letter like `D:`